# ESP32 and TP4056 lipo charging

Tags: esp32, lipo, load, tp4056

I'm currently working on a project involving an ESP32-S3 Microcontroller. I want to implement a few things that are very hard for me to figure out. This is my current TP4056 charging logic + battery protection circuitry.

[image]

I already made a PCB with this design and it does charge the battery, but I found a few problems with this design.

1. When I do not have a Battery attached, I get a very loud feeping noise (high pitch), and I wonder from which component it comes. Power gets delivered anyway but that loud noise can not be right.
2. I want be able to charge the battery and use the Micro-Controller at the same time. Furthermore I want that, if I charge the battery that it does not provide the current for my ESP32, but instead use the power of the charger. I think this is called load distribution. I saw this [schematic](https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056-page2.html), but I do not know how to implement this design in my current schematic

[image]

3. I want to implement a switch (with 3 pins)

> First State: Do not connect the battery and only use the +5V as an output

> Second State: Connect the battery

I'm wrapping my head around this for days now, so I would be very happy if someone could show me a way to implement these points in my design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may have a faulty component somewhere that is making that high pitched noise. I suggest to disconnect the PCM (protection circuit module) from the battery charger and connect the battery directly to the charger to see if this still makes the noise (making sure you do not short the battery etc.)
2. There are ICs that are designed to switch inputs to output with very little power loss, especially for power distribution multiplexing. I suggest you read about Power Switch ICs for Power Distribution applications. Look them up on distributor websites like Digikey, Farnell etc. that sell them and pick one that suits your application.
3. An input power distribution switch may also solve this third problem without to much fuss, but first look at solving the first two ...

Comment: Do you have an example of such an IC?

Comment: Take a look at TPS2116 or similar to get an idea of is available ... good luck